# How to ignore default values while serializing json with Newtonsoft.Json

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm using `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert` to serialize a `Textbox` (WinForms) into json and I want the serialization to skip properties with default values or empty arrays.

I'v tried to use `NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore` in `JsonSerializerSettings` but is doesn't seem to affect anything.

Here is the full code sample (simplified):

```
JsonSerializerSettings settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
                {
                    Formatting = Formatting.None,
                    DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Ignore,
                    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
                    ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore,
                    ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace,
                    PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.None,
                    ConstructorHandling = ConstructorHandling.AllowNonPublicDefaultConstructor,
                };

    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(textbox, settings);
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Can I check? In the title and the start of the question, you ask about **serializing**, but the example shows **deserializing**. Which is it that you are trying to do
?

Comment: @MarcGravell: Correct, sorry. Copy-pasted the wrong line.

Answer (score 9):

You could use the standard conditional-serialization pattern:

```
private int bar = 6; // default value of 6
public int Bar { get { return bar;} set { bar = value;}}
public bool ShouldSerializeBar()
{
    return Bar != 6;
}
```

The key is a `public bool ShouldSerialize*()` method, where `*` is the member-name. This pattern is also used by `XmlSerializer`, protobuf-net, `PropertyDescriptor`, etc.

This does, of course, mean you need access to the type.

Comment: I want to serialize different (winform) controls so this is not an option.

Comment: @gil in that case you may need to do it all fairly manually, by registering a converter.

Comment: Is there anyway I can subclass the regular converter and just add an if to filter out the props I don't want to be serialized?

Comment: @gil it looks like you'd still have to enumerate the properties yourself for the WriteJson API. For ReadJson you can probably use serializer.Populate. No easy options, I'm afraid..