# protobuf-net conditional serialization given as initialize on Serializer.Serialize()

Tags: c#, serialization, protobuf-net

I am try to make conditional serialization base on rules that I give the moment I make the Serialization.

I know that I can use the `ShouldSerialize`+`Name`

```
[ProtoContract]
public class SomeType {
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string Name {get;set;}

    private bool ShouldSerializeName() {
       // return true to serialize Name, false otherwise
    }
}
```

**But** what I need is like this example on `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert`  where I give the settings for what i am going to serialize the moment of serialization.

```
var oResolFilter = new ShouldSerializeContractResolver();
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = oResolFilter };
var Results = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this, settings);
```

and

```
class ShouldSerializeContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        JsonProperty property = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);    
        property.ShouldSerialize = true ; // ( or false)    
        return property;
    }
}
```

So the question is - how can I do something similar as the `JsonConvert` on `ProtoBuf-Net`

#### reference

I look on most of answers, and on the examples and the source code on protobuf-net but fail to locate a similar solution... here are few questions that I look.

[.net serialization: how to selectively ignore data fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11880666/net-serialization-how-to-selectively-ignore-data-fields/11880902#11880902)
[Conditional serialization with protobuf-net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35469388/conditional-serialization-with-protobuf-net)
[Protobuf-net serialization of object (generic) throws error No serializer defined for type: System.Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64978758/protobuf-net-serialization-of-object-generic-throws-error-no-serializer-define/64982106#64982106)
[How to ignore default values while serializing json with Newtonsoft.Json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11628353/how-to-ignore-default-values-while-serializing-json-with-newtonsoft-json/11628495#11628495)

json.net example:
[Newtonsoft JSON ShouldSerialize and inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42099348/newtonsoft-json-shouldserialize-and-inheritance/42100030#42100030)

Comment: How about a before-serialization callback with a serialization context that has the info you need to make decisions?

Comment: @MarcGravell and how can I do that ?

Comment: I'm not at a PC, but: there should be a [ProtoBeforeSerialization] attribute, that you can put on a method of your choosing, and which can optionally take a `SerializationContext` that allows you to pass in external state (you should be able to provide that state via the API, or perhaps when creating the ProroWriter - again, I'm not at a PC)

Comment: @MarcGravell thank you, I am going to search for it

Comment: k; if you can't find it, ping me and I'll whip up an example

Comment: @MarcGravell Do you have an example for above ? Thanks.